# llvm: why is adce more aggressive than dce

Tags: llvm

As both `adce` and `dce` are the optimizers in `llvm-opt` and the optimal directions are different(`adce` considers all the insts dead first and `dce` considers all the insts live first). but why is `adce` more aggressive than `dce`? And one more question is that are there an example(a .ll file)'s outputs(one is optimized by `dce` and another by`adce`) are different?

Comment: Aggressive, in this context, means that adce considers an instruction dead when there's any doubt, and will remove it. dce leaves it in when there's doubt. Both of them toggle when there's a definite reason to, which is another way of saying the same thing.